# Insert to SQL Server from table type fails if more than 1 row

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datatable

The following procedure gets data from C# as a datatable. I am sure that the table is sent with multiple rows. If it does have multiple rows, then no data is inserted, but if the data table contains only one row, it inserts it without any problems.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MergeContactInfo]
    @ContactInfo dbo.[PersonContactTableType] READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    MERGE INTO PersonContact AS pc
    USING @ContactInfo AS ci ON pc.Person = ci.Person

    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
       UPDATE SET pc.Value = ci.Value, pc.Type = ci.Type
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
       INSERT VALUES(ci.Person, ci.Type, ci.Value);
END
```

Any solution why multiple rows not inserted and only one row is inserted, there's no unique constraints.

@Contact Info is the following

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[PersonContactTableType] AS TABLE(
    [Person] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Type] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Person] ASC) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
GO
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what @Contactinfo may contain?

Comment: What error are you getting when you have multiple rows.

Comment: No Error at all, just not inserting the data.

Comment: @Contact Info is a Table type of Contact info 
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[PersonContactTableType] AS TABLE(
 [Person] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Type] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
 [Value] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [Person] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
GO

Comment: Are you sure you are not just hitting the matched condition?

Comment: It hits and inserts when the datatable contains only 1 row, but not inserting when I send datatable with multiple rows

Comment: I suggest you add a step in your SP that just writes the table value out to a table inside SQL Server. This will let you verify that multiple rows were received and will also let you manually merge the records and confirm that there is no error. You should probably include whatever code sends the rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your C# datatable content. Each number in "Person" field must be unique. Procedure perfectly works as designed.

Comment: The problem is that the person is not unique !!, the person can contain multiple contact info .. I think this is the problem. how to insert multiple rows with the same person ID

Comment: That depends on your business logic. Is "Person" column in your "PersonContact" table unique or Primary Key?

Comment: not unique nor primary key, not in the data table and not in the sql table, and I have no idea why I can't insert 2 records for the same person.

Comment: At first, it is very well designed SP. At second, it is regular normalization approach not to have duplicates. I'd guess you need to add column [Type] to your PK to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works perfect on SQL side,
I tested playing with the content of the table variable and I see that it is merged with table data as expected

```
declare @CI as [PersonContactTableType];
insert into @CI values (11,1,'ERALPER'),(12,2,'The Phantom'),(13,2,'Lord Vader'),(14,1,'Kodyaz')
exec [MergeContactInfo] @CI;
go
select * from PersonContact
```